# Filtering a list of classes with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of class. I need to filter the list using some text.

```
class Person
{
  string Name;
  int age;
}
```

I have a list of Person class

```
list<Person> PersonList;
```

i have 100 values in PersonList;
Now I need to filter it using some text.
I wrote as

```
this.PersonList.Where(item => item.Name.Contains(txtFilter.Text)).ToList();
```

But it does not return the expected result..Can any one help me?

Comment: It looks ok. Have you debuged your code and view the `txtFilter.Text`?

Comment: yes it is getting a value. If i have a name with "john" and i type "h" in the text box..it need to return the list with "john"..but it does not wrk.

Comment: How do you check the list? Are you setting your new list? Or are you checking the `PersonList`? I mean if you will check the `PersonList` it will be the same. You must set your new List.

Comment: What do you mean `but it does not wrk`? Does it return whole list? Or nothing? And please answer my previous comment also.

Comment: Saying "it does not work" without any explanation of _what_ doesn't work is one of the most obnoxious things you can do when asking for tech help. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to preserve the result return by the linq statement in some variable like this

```
var filteredList = this.PersonList.Where(item => item.Name.Contains(txtFilter.Text)).ToList();
```